# matplotlib : how to have automatic x axis as to lenght of list in y axis

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

```
x = np.array()
y = np.array(profit_loss)
```

I want my x axis to be from 0 to the length of the list of my y axis. I want it to automatically update whenever I add more values to the profit_loss list. 
Tried len(profit_loss), but it doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it out.

It's range(len(profit_loss))